# what's wrong with writing the code: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, apex

```
CREATE TABLE comenzi
(
    id_comanda NUMBER(5) CONSTRAINT id_comanda_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    nume_companie VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
    persoana_contact VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
    data_comanda DATE,
    data_expediere DATE,
    loc_expediere VARCHAR2(24) UNIQUE;
)

CREATE TABLE detalii_comenzi
(
    id_comanda NUMBER(5) CONSTRAINT id_comanda_fk REFERENCES comenzi(id_comenzi),
    id_produs NUMBER(5) CONSTRAINT id_produs_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    pret_unitar NUMBER(7),
    cantitate NUMBER(7) NOT NULL;
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using right data types. Please try using below code.

```
CREATE TABLE #comenzi
(
     ID_COMANDA INT CONSTRAINT id_comanda_pk PRIMARY KEY, 
     NUME_COMPANIE VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
     PERSOANA_CONTACT VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
     DATA_COMANDA DATE,
     DATA_EXPEDIERE DATE,
     LOC_EXPEDIERE VARCHAR(24) UNIQUE 
)

CREATE TABLE detalii_comenzi
(
    id_comanda INT CONSTRAINT id_comanda_fk REFERENCES #comenzi (ID_COMANDA),
    id_produs INT CONSTRAINT id_produs_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    pret_unitar INT, 
    cantitate INT NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option